Unable to upload image from my React-Native app to Appwrite
I have create a React-Native code to upload images to my appwrite storage but i am not able to and getting error. Can anyone please review the code and give me a concrete answer
My appwrite logic -
const client = new Client();

client
  .setEndpoint(appwriteConfig.endpoint) // Your Appwrite Endpoint
  .setProject(appwriteConfig.projectId) // Your project ID
  .setPlatform(appwriteConfig.platform); // Your application ID or bundle ID.

const account = new Account(client);
const avatar = new Avatars(client);
const databases = new Databases(client);
const storage = new Storage(client);

export const uploadImageToAppwrite = async (urin) => {
  try {
    const result = await storage.createFile(
      appwriteConfig.storageId,
      ID.unique(),
      {
        name: "photo.jpg",
        type: "image/jpg",
        uri: urin,
      },
      [
        Permission.read(Role.any()),
        Permission.update(Role.users()),
        Permission.delete(Role.users()),
      ]
    );

    console.log("File uploaded successfully:", result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("File upload failed:", error);
  }
};`

Here urin is the file path "file:///data/user/0/com.anonymous.ecommerce/cache/rn_image_picker_lib_temp_84dae6a9-44fb-4146-a7d6-ad80081a09f3.jpg"
I have used blob also but it also is not working. Currently in the above code i get this output in the log =
LOG  File uploaded successfully: undefined

Any help is much appreciated
I tried the above code i gave and file should be uploaded in DB but I am getting output as undefined
